# Not able to see Delta table data in azure data lake gen1

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

I have created a delta table in Azure data lake gen1. But, I am not able to see any data in data lake via azure portal.
But, when I run 'ls' command on that delta table path I can see the files present.

code is:

```
groupsUpdatePath = 'dbfs:/mnt/datalakeg2/referencedata/Groups.csv'

groupsUpdate = spark.read.csv(groupsUpdatePath,
                      inferSchema = 'true',
                      header = 'true',
                      mode="DROPMALFORMED",
                      timestampFormat="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                      escape = "\"").distinct()

groupsUpdate.write.option("path", "/mnt/datalake/Experiments/Example").saveAsTable("exampleTable")
```

Can anyone guide what could be the issue?
Thanks

Comment: sounds like a permission issue, if you can't see a file, but databricks mount is able to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to write a delta table in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 use the following commands:
As Chen Hirsh it might be an permission issue.

```py
#create mount point for ADLS gen 1
configs = {
   "fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type": "CustomAccessTokenProvider",
   "fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.custom.provider": spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.passthrough.adls.tokenProviderClassName")
 }

 dbutils.fs.mount(
   source = "adl://<storage-account-name>.azuredatalakestore.net/<directory-name>",
   mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
   extra_configs = configs)

#Write the file to ADLS gen 1 as delta table
groupsUpdate.write.option("path", "/mnt/mnt1sampledemo1").saveAsTable("exampleTable")
```

Also go to ADLS gen 1 account go to Data explorer >> Access.

[image]

Check user you are trying to access has appropriate permissions.

[image]

I can see files are created under the Mountpoint of ADLS gen 1 folder.

[image]